# How do I hide Cocos2d-x GL verts/calls labels?

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am new to Cocos2d-x and I'm using C++.

There are labels like **GL verts: 12** and **GL calls: 2** that are really for development and debugging, and I'd like to hide them.

How do I disable, remove, or hide the labels in Cocos2d-x?

Comment: You should try to use the correct capitalization of projects/libraries/frameworks/languages you are referencing.  You should describe your problem separately before posing your question.  You should make sure to close with a concise question.

Comment: Corrected my own typo. Derp.

Comment: Find in your Appdelegate.cpp the line 'director->setDisplayStats(true)' and set 'false'.

Answer (score 3):

In your `AppDelegate.cpp` which is under `classes` folder edit the following line form

```
director->setDisplayStats(true);
```

to

```
director->setDisplayStats(false);
```

Also I would advice you too  read the code, it generally helps.